# Tomcat: web application java class files/jar location

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, ant, tomcat7

I'm fairly new to Web Application deployment. Here is my scenario. I have to deploy a java web-application onto Tomcat 7. There is not UI as such (on this tomcat) , just REST services offered by the Java backend. Some kind of 'app' will connect to this server for the REST services. I have to use ANT to build these and I have successfully done that and have a jar now, but where do i place this jar such that i can use these services by placing the REST calls. Do i need a .war file for this scenario? Is the approach I'm using correct to the requirement that i have?.
Please guide.

Comment: What implementation are you using? You can find a [JAX-WS example here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) or a [Jersey example here](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/RESTful-Web-services-made-easy)

Comment: @c.s. I'm using Jersey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat run as java web container.
You will need to have a Web archive, .war-file to deploy your application.
Or having your application as a directory with web.xml (in web-inf sub-directory etc).

During deployment Tomcat will need to read the web.xml, which is the most important file for telling what app and configuration you need from tomcat.

After reading the web.xml, tomcat starts the web application as given.

a JAR file, will not deploy your application, but just make classes available for tomcat.

As you are using ANT to build the app, see the WAR-task (which is an extension of JAR) in Ant manual.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html It will help you making the WAR file and the web.xml etc.

Comment: As you suggested, i created the MyApp.war file and and put it under the webapps dir. 

Now, the webapp content structure is 
"webapps/MyApp"
and the classes are under
"webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/com/rest/restjersey"

But when i try to send a GET call on one of the services, it says : "Cannot GET /MyApp/rest/..."

Is there something that i might be missing here? I checked the 'Path' of the url. There seems to be no mistake there.

Comment: Figured it out. Had missed the `<lib>` tag under the task for constructing the war file